# How to set x-api-key in codeigniter Restserver_controller for POST request?

Tags: postman, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-restserver

How to setup `x-api-key` for Post request, I got the following error in postman plugin.

*Post request error in postman google chrome plugin (Screenshot)*

[image]

Any Suggestions? What is wrong here?

Comment: this X-API-KEY is probably a header, not a query string parameter.

Comment: @lan Luca Thank you for your suggestion. It works fine.